# Heroku run python throws an error ModulenotfoundError

Tags: python, django, heroku

I tried to run `heroku run Python manage.py migrate`

it throws an error `ModulenotfoundError no module named django`

And also it shows

```
ImportError: Could not import django.are you sure it's installed
and available on you Python path environment variable? 
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I tried all of these I check my django it's working fine,

if I tried `Python manage.py run server` the server is running without any issues.

Comment: Your python environment isn't what heroku is running, heroku needs its environment setup too

Comment: Actually im working in an virtual environment named "project1".  Is it required to create a seperate environment for heroku

Answer (score 0):

create requirments.txt in root directory of your project

Comment: yes I tried it before , "pip freeze > requirements.txt" and also installed too , but still facing this error

Comment: how did you manage to get this solved? Im having trouble here as well